# How do I get Chrome 17 to prerender pages during autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome

Google announced Chrome 17 today; their top advertised feature was a [prerender feature for the omnibox](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2012/02/faster-browsing-safer-downloading.html).

> When you start typing in the omnibox and the URL autocompletes to a site you’re very likely to visit, Chrome will prerender the page, so it will appear faster--sometimes, even instantly--as soon as you hit Enter.

But, I can't get it to work. I monitor my network traffic (using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) and type "google.com" in the omnibox, waiting for some magic to happen; nothing. It autocompletes as soon as I type "go", but it doesn't prerender.

Same for "facebook.com" ("fa") "stackoverflow.com" ("st"). The network traffic only starts once I hit Enter.

Is there some way to force it to prerender for certain pages?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version?

Comment: "Google Chrome is up to date (17.0.963.46)"

Answer (score 0):

[Web Developer's Guide to Prerendering in Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender.html) says,

> Beginning in Chrome 17, Chrome itself will initiate prerendering in some cases, based on the user's interactions with the address bar.

So I dont think it'll work always. Use it for sometime. Maybe it'll prerender the pages you visit most.

Comment: It performs the analysis based on the history. If he has already been using Chrome for a while, then that is not the problem.

Comment: Yes. I've also seen prerendering while searching at google.com, where you search for a query, wait couple of seconds and the top result usually gets prerendered.

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, I have been using Chrome for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which URLs are likely to be prerendered by going to `chrome://predictors` in Chrome 20 or later. This page shows which URLs Chrome thinks you might navigate to after entering particular text in the Omnibox.

Similarly, you can use `chrome://net-internals#prerender` to find out when a site is being prerendered.